# How to check a word in a file there is or not the word

Tags: java

I was there a problem with my code, where I need a function to check whether there is the word I'm looking for or not in a file, if there is then it will return true, and if it fails will return false.

```
public void MyFunction(){
    String theWord = "Im very handsome";
    File theFile = new File("/home/rams/Desktop/tes.txt");
    if(CheckWord(theWord, theFile)){
      // so I will continue my coding, while I stuck :-(
    }
}

public void CheckWord(String theWord, File theFile){
   // what the code to search a word, which the word is variable theWord, the file is variable theFile
   // return true if in file there a word
   // return false if in file there not a word
   // thanks my brother
}
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Have you tried anything (beside asking strangers to do it for you)?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

Comment: @Pshemo: Good education, Okay I still search how to read from file and the compare to links above from Mr.Jared n Mr.Ced-b.

Comment: @HaicalRams SO has already few answered questions about reading contend of file. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716503/1393766), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/326390/1393766) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3402735/1393766). Also String class has build in method to check if string contains some substring, but since it can give false positive results (`"something".contains("thing")` returns true even if there is no separate `"thing"` word inside) people tend to use regex with \b - [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one-liner method:

```
public boolean CheckWord(String theWord, File theFile) {
    return (new Scanner(theFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next()).contains(theWord);
}
```

Comment: solved, thanks, but this need FileNotFoundException, and I just add try and catch(FileNotFoundException). Thank you very much Sir.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Yes it needs `FileNotFoundException` to be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems a homework assignment, I won´t give you the code of the solution. You need to:

1. Your function CheckWord must return a boolean instead of void
2. Read the text in the file ([What is simplest way to read a file into String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402735/what-is-simplest-way-to-read-a-file-into-string-in-java))
3. Compare the text in the file with your word (http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
4. Return true or false depending on the result of the comparison