# Difference between '\Z' and '\z' in java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex, java-6

What is the difference between the JDK6 `java.util.regex.Pattern`'s "Boundary matchers" '\z' and '\Z'?

Background: I was trying to read a UTF-8 encoded file's contents into a `String`. Came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403112/438758). I discovered that `java.util.scanner.useDelimeter` uses a `java.util.regex.Pattern`. The previously mentione solution proposes '\Z'.

Comment: Can you explain in detail what confused you after you had [read the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)? Your question reads very much as though you saw the confusing matcher characters and immediately posted on SO without any prior research.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the duplicate question. Somehow this question did not turn up when I googled using '\Z' '\z' and java.util.regex.Pattern.

Comment: @DuncanJones. My question was along the practical difference. On hindsight, it appears that I should have posted the code that I tried with.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html, the difference is that:

```
\Z  The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
\z  The end of the input
```