# What is simplest way to write to a file from a String in java?

Tags: java, io

First I like..

[What is simplest way to read a file into String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402735/what-is-simplest-way-to-read-a-file-into-string-in-java)

```
String content = new Scanner(new File("H:MM-Full-AF.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
System.out.println(content);
```

But then I was like.. What be the inverse?

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: *"But then I was like.. What be the inverse?"* And what did you see when you looked in the `java.io` documentation?

Comment: Writers have `write` method. How simpler you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code can do what you want if you don't want to use any additional libraries like apache commons. However you may have to put some try catch around it.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = null;
String content = "A string to be written to file";
File newTextFile = new File("C:\\output.txt");
fileWriter = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
fileWriter.write(content);
fileWriter.close();
```

This is another way of doing the same...

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\output.txt""));
out.write("A string to be written to file");
out.close();
```

Comment: Very simple, much appreciated!