# exception in thread main java.util.nosuchelementexception with new Scanner(file)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I have a problem with my code,I get this error all the time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at audio.AudioSecrets.main(AudioSecrets.java:32)
Java Result: 1
```

my problem is this ligne:

```
contents = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().toCharArray(); //
```

The `\\Z` delimiter in combination with `.next()` will read input until there isn't any left.

how can I input the file to my program,thanks for help

Comment: It looks like you're trying to put the whole file into a String.  This is dealt with at [What is simplest way to read a file into String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402735/what-is-simplest-way-to-read-a-file-into-string) which is why I voted to close as a duplicate of that one.  It's not that this is a bad question - it's a good one.  It's just that this has been done before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check `hasNext()` before calling `next()`. Probably there are no elements matching your criteria.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
s.useDelimiter("\\Z");
if(s.hasNext()) {
   contents = s.next().toCharArray();
}
```