# Reading just one token from a file

Tags: java

Thanks everybody for the help.
What I need to do is the following:

**Open a file for reading**

**Read the first token [String] in the file**

**Report the next Read_Cursor_Position**

**Return the token**

**Close the file**

**Reopen the file**

**Read the *second* token from the file**

and so on and so forth until all the necessary data has been read.
I am new to Java, but in C++  tellg or tellp is used to extract the cursor position and getline for reading just the one token from a file. 
I hope this explanation better explain my question.

After writing a method that outputs data with a delimiter to a UTF file, I am now trying to extract the data from the UTF file. The way the data has to be extracted is one token at the time, the tokens, as I said before, have a delimiter and all Java has to do is read the file's token until the delimiter is found.
Here is the code for the writer method:

```
public void writeData(String data) throws IOException {
    try {
        dout.writeUTF(data);
        dout.writeBytes("^");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and here is the reader:

```
public void readData() throws IllegalStateException {
    try {
        apstr = new StringBuilder();
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            apstr.delete(0,apstr.length());
            apstr.append(scan.next());
            System.out.println("The token is: " + apstr);
        }
    } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
        scan.close();
        throw e;
    }
    scan.close();
}
```

The file contains the following data:
Java^C++^PHP^
and the output is:
Java^C++^PHP^
but all I want to read is the word Java

How can I make Java do the same thing?

by the way, how do I go about posting a new question? There is no button on this web page that says "Post a new question". Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the Scanner is reading from the file? Then you don't want to use writeUTF. writeUTF doesn't encode the way you think it does. Use a Writer and specify UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Btw, you _cannot_ possibly be posting your exact code. The printline does not match your alleged output. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should write to your file using a Writer. If you want to use utf-8 encoding do something like

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("somepath"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

then do

pw.println("some text");

using DataOutputStream for stuff that you will be reading with a scanner isn't going to work.

Answer (score -1):

Use the [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html?is-external=true).

It contains a constructor `StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)` -- in which your delimiter will be the carat ("^") character, and a `nextToken()` function to return the next token as a String.

Also, this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402735/what-is-simplest-way-to-read-a-file-into-string) demonstrates various options to reading your file into a `String`.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is legacy class, to tokenize string you should use `String#split();`

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help.