# Is there a way to pass ObjectMapper's JsonNode Object to selenium's sendKeys method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, objectmapper

I want to read a JSON file and pass its content to a browser page using selenium-java. Using ObjectMapper, I am able to read the file OK.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode payload = mapper.readTree(new File(baseUtil.getPayload()));
System.out.println(payload); //payload is printed out OK
driver.findElement(By.id("demo-payload")).sendKeys((payload)); //error on this line: Cannot resolve method 'sendKeys(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)'
```

When attempting to pass the file content to selenium's `sendKeys` method, I got a compilation error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'sendKeys(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)'
```

I tried resolving the issue by casting the argument to CharSequence, this way:

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("demo-payload")).sendKeys((CharSequence) payload);
```

Output:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
```

Is there a way to pass the JSON file content to Selenium's `sendKeys`?

Comment: @AndreyKotov, this works perfectly. If you put the answer in the provided answer box, I can mark it as an acceptable answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.sendKeys(mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNodePayload))` or `.sendKeys(jsonNodePayload.toString())`. Also you don't need to read this value from a file like a `JsonNode` because further you simply put everything as `String` to `sendKeys` method. Read it as a [string from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295945/4393666).