# Obtain byte array of a JPEG image without compressing

Tags: java, android, jpeg

I would like to obtain the byte array of a JPEG image **without** using the following method:

```
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/photo.jpg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason not to just load the file itself as a normal `FileInputStream` etc? (Personally I like Guava's `Files.toByteArray()` as a simple way of loading a file, but I don't know the status of Guava on Android.)

Comment: May I know how do I achieve that?

Comment: @androidnoob: Do you know how to read from a file at all? I would strongly suggest reading a book on core Java (collections, streams etc) before trying to go much further, to be honest. I'm not trying to be rude, but it's really important to have a good grasp of the basics of a platform before trying anything serious, and a Q&A site like StackOverflow isn't the best way to get that knowledge.

Comment: @androidnoob, for reading a file into byte array, I (also) think you're best off using a utility method from a library like [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) or [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/). (If the whole lib is too big, you could just take the relevant classes.) See e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058003/beautiful-way-to-read-file-into-byte-array-in-java) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks, figured out how to do it myself

Answer (score 1):

If you consider it as a normal file type, then it would solve your problem.

here is the code

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/download/The-Rock2.jpg");
byte[] bytes = getBytesFromFile(file);



public byte[] getBytesFromFile(File file) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        long length = file.length();

        bytes = new byte[(int) length];

        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
        }

        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
                  //TODO Write your catch method here
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: An empty catch block, catching all exceptions? Ick.

Comment: So you're *inviting* someone who apparently doesn't know how to use streams to copy code which follows *very bad practice* (oh, and I've just noticed you don't close the file on exception), without including *any* sort of warning on it? Double ick.

Comment: Also, it doesn't make much sense to throw an IOException with an error message if you enclose it in a try-catch which silently ignores everything, including that exception...