# Android read image from sdcard. Wrong size

Tags: android, image, sd-card, filesize

I am creating an android app and want to read a file from sdcard and send it to a rest webservice. Everything works fine but when I read the file from sdcard its filesize is much bigger than its originalsize. A 10 KB file is getting 260 KB.

I am doing the following...

```
File f = new File(uri);
Log.d("ORIGINAL FILESIZE:"+f.length());
```

**Filesize 10752 Bytes on SDCARD.**

This is exactly the same size the image has on the phone.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri);
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bao);
Log.d("FILESIZE AFTER:"+bao.size());
```

**Filesize 260904 Bytes after decode / compress.**

This is the filesize the server receives and writes to disk. 
It's the same Image and Quality but about 20 times bigger.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your original file is a jpeg with high compression rate, it's normal that the decoded bitmap is much larger, especially if you use a quality of 100 in the `compress()` method (which means high quality).

Did you try using `compress()` with a lower quality value (cf [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)) ?

Comment: hi but doesn't the bmp.compress method just read the already compressed image from disk?. I don't want to compress it double times. I want to leave the quality as it is.

Comment: not sure. Maybe not. I just need to read the image from sdcard and need to get a byte[] array. Is there a better way doing it?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058003/beautiful-way-to-read-file-into-byte-array-in-java

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong. Or at least it could be. The bytes rapresentation of a bitmap in memory, requires (a 32-bit image) `height  * widht * 4` bytes. And of course it differs from the file size becaouse of the compression.

Comment: yea but if I write the same file to disc again then the size of the newly created file is still 20 times bigger as it was before.

Comment: if apply compress with the same pairo of compress algo/quality, yes it has

Comment: I tried using the same compress level as before when I created the image. The filesize is the same now but the quality of the newly created image seems worse.

Comment: are you starting from the compressed image and compress it again?

Comment: that's why you are getting an image of worse quality