# How to read first and last 64kb of a video file in Java?

Tags: java

I want to use a subtitle API. It requires a md5 hash of first and last 64kb of the video file.
I know how to do the md5 part just want to know how will I achieve to get the 128kb of data.

An example of API is given in Python but sadly I do not understand it.

```
    #this hash function receives the name of the file and returns the hash code
def get_hash(name):
    readsize = 64 * 1024
    with open(name, 'rb') as f:
        size = os.path.getsize(name)
        data = f.read(readsize)
        f.seek(-readsize, os.SEEK_END)
        data += f.read(readsize)
    return hashlib.md5(data).hexdigest()
```

http://thesubdb.com/api/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to know how to read 64kb of data in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elegant way to read file into byte\[\] array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058003/elegant-way-to-read-file-into-byte-array-in-java)

Comment: Yes.
first 64kb and last 64kb of the file. Combined.

Comment: See the duplicate, and the link in the duplicate. It's pretty straight forward I think.

Comment: You keep saying 64kb, but your code example reads 64KB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("d:/1.avi");
    byte[] a = new byte[64 * 1024];
    in.read(a);   //head
    long p = in.getChannel().size() - 64 * 1024;
    in.getChannel().position(p);
    in.read(a);   //tail
```