# How to read bytes from a file to a byte[] array?

Tags: java, file, byte, arrays

I am writing a Java program which encrypts a given text using RSA, and saves the encrypted bytes(byte[] array) in a .txt file. There is a separate decryption program which reads these bytes. Now I want to read the same bytes into a byte[] in to the decryption program. How can this be done using Java?

```
BufferedReader brip = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("encrypted.txt"));
Strings CurrentLine = brip.readLine();
byte[] b = sCurrentLine.getBytes();
```

This is how I have been reading the data from the file. But it's wrong because it converts the bytes in sCurrentLine variable into again bytes.

Comment: Have you tried anything to read it yet? Please demonstrate some attempt at solving your problem by showing example code. If you don't know where to start, Google is always a good bet.

Comment: show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Everything is wrong here. Encrypted data is not text; shouldn't be stored in a file named .txt; doesn't contain lines; and can't be read with a `Reader.` Use an `InputStream.`

Answer (score 29):

In Java 7 you can use the [readAllBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) method of Files class. See below:

```
Path fileLocation = Paths.get("C:\\test_java\\file.txt");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);
```

There are many other ways to do it see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058003/elegant-way-to-read-file-into-byte-array-in-java) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)

Comment: This only works with smaller files.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me, in an android project so hopefully, it will work for you.

```
 private byte[] getByte(String path) {
    byte[] getBytes = {};
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        getBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        is.read(getBytes);
        is.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getBytes;
}
```