# Convert docx, doc to base64 android

Tags: android, base64, document, docx, doc

I am trying to get the docx file as shown below

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == MainActivity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the Uri of the selected file
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String uriString = uri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            filepath =path;
            String displayName = null;

            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        txtFilename.setText(displayName);
                        filename = displayName;

                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                displayName = myFile.getName();
                txtFilename.setText(displayName);
                filename = displayName;

            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Now the result is :

Path: `/content:/com.estrongs.files/storage/emulated/0/Download/Imp%20Values.docx`

Filename: `Imp Values.docx`

Now how do I convert this document to base64 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never tried it, but I think You could convert Your doc to byte[] like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058003/elegant-way-to-read-file-into-byte-array-in-java   and then convert this byte[] into Base64 with Base64.encodeToString(yourByteArray,Base64.DEFAULT). But I read something that this will grow up Your file size....

Comment: for my understanding, it must be like converting an image into Base64.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, Hope it will work, I did for .pdf and .doc

```
public static String convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

        Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

For picking file :

```
private void chooseFile() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: @Nisarg- Attempt to get length of null array exception

Comment: please check [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/8d68195d84318a3dec81/raw/64fdbda95b1f0428174d248286193e59d9c96009/gistfile1.txt)

Comment: getting now file size as '0'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105685/discussion-between-nisarg-and-coder).

Comment: @Nisarg- Thanks for your time :) Worked pretty well

Comment: FileNotFound Exception @Nisarg

Comment: @Banku Make sure your input file exists !!

Comment: @Nisarg Attempt to get length of null array exception sir, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The above code always returns a nullpointerexception but this solved it without any error

```
// Converting File to Base64.encode String type using Method
    public String getStringFile(File f) {
        InputStream inputStream = null; 
        String encodedFile= "", lastVal;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];//specify the size to allow
        int bytesRead;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Base64OutputStream output64 = new Base64OutputStream(output, Base64.DEFAULT);

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        output64.close();
        encodedFile =  output.toString();
        } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e1 ) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        lastVal = encodedFile;
        return lastVal;
    }
```

Comment: this trows `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 453230608 byte allocation with 6291456 free bytes and 165MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 235231304, growth limit 402653184` at line `output64.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)`