# Convert Pdf File path to Base64 String

Tags: android, pdf, base64, document, docx

I am trying to convert my pdf file to Base64 string as like below

```
public static String convertFileToByteArray(File f) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 11];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();

        Log.e("Byte array", ">" + byteArray);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

But as it returning me null pointer exception. As i refereed this link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35866301/4608769

Can anybody provide me perfect solution.

This is my error log that i am getting

```
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65539, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.fileexplorer.myprovider/external_files/Download/android_tutorial.pdf flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.voicenetpulse.pbxanywhereapp/com.voicenetpulse.pbxanywhereapp.kotlin.welcome.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)
at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
at com.voicenetpulse.pbxanywhereapp.fax.Fax_Fragment.convertFileToByteArray(Fax_Fragment.java:548)
at com.voicenetpulse.pbxanywhereapp.fax.Fax_Fragment.onActivityResult(Fax_Fragment.java:511)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7128)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4142)
... 9 more
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)
at android.util.Base64.encodeToString(Base64.java:456)
at com.voicenetpulse.pbxanywhereapp.fax.Fax_Fragment.convertFileToByteArray(Fax_Fragment.java:548)
at com.voicenetpulse.pbxanywhereapp.fax.Fax_Fragment.onActivityResult(Fax_Fragment.java:511)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:164)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7128)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4142)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1572)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6205)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: Don't convert the PDF yourself, use Apache Commons https://stackoverflow.com/a/859076/6110433

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/utsengar/1276960)

Comment: @R2R , java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: did you see the `(FileName.java:lineNumber)` in your stacktrace? if so, what line is it?

Comment: yes, in this line  "return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT); "

Comment: byte array returning me null.

Comment: no, it cannot be `return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);` - there is no `null` object which could throw `NullPointerException` - why dont you simply post your stacktrace?

Comment: most likely your app fails here: `Base64#encode(byte[] input, int flags)`, not in your `return` statement

Comment: @pskink , i have posted my error log , please can u check.

Comment: as i said: `android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java:494)` - you are passing `null` to `encodeToString` method  - see sources of `Base64.java`

Comment: I got it, where i am doing wrong, now null pointer exception has resolved, but one issue i am facing in pdf files. byte will only read .txt file but for pdf it returning 0 byte. so any change for importing pdf.