# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException

Tags: java, eclipse, unmarshalling, jibx, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to bind an xml file(as a `byte[]`) to a java object. This is my code-

```
public voidinputConfigXML(String xmlfile, byte[] xmlData) {
    IBindingFactory bFact = BindingDirectory.getFactory(GroupsDTO.class);
                IUnmarshallingContext uctx = bFact.createUnmarshallingContext();
                groups = (GroupsDTO) uctx.unmarshalDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData), "UTF8");
}
```

The `unmarshalDocument()` is giving me this exception. What do i do?

**FYI: Running as JUnit test case**

The following is the stacktrace -

```
    Error parsing document (line 1, col 1)
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 (position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1) 
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1519)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.XMLPullReaderFactory$XMLPullReader.next(XMLPullReaderFactory.java:291)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.toStart(UnmarshallingContext.java:451)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:2755)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshallingContext.java:2905)
        at abc.dra.DRAAPI.inputConfigXML(DRAAPI.java:31)
        at abc.dra.XMLToObject_Test.test(XMLToObject_Test.java:34)
        [...]
```

This is my code that forms byte[]-

```
void test() {
String xmlfile = "output.xml"
File file = new File(xmlfile);
byte[] xmlData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
groups = dra.inputConfigXML(xmlfile, xmlData);
}
```

Comment: Please append the Stacktrace. There may be interesting information within it.

Comment: Please add abc.dra.DRAAPI.inputConfigXML to your Question

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach The code that i've added in the beginning is **abc.dra.DRAAPI.inputConfigXML**

Comment: No, the interesting part is the creation of **xmlData**. And that piece of code is missing.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach i've added the code at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 2):

The ByteArrayInputstream is empty:

```
only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not \u0 
(position: START_DOCUMENT seen \u0... @1:1)
```

means, that a \u0 Bit was found as first char within the XML.

Ensure you have content within your `byte[]` and the UTF-8 don't start with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark).

I don't think, that the BOM is your problem here, but I often encountert regarding BOM and java.

**update**

You don't fill the `byte[]`. You have to read the file-content into the `byte[]`:
read this: [File to byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)

By the way: `byte[] xmlData = new byte[(int) file.length()];` is bad code-style, becaus you will run into problems with larger XML-files. If they are larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you will read a corrupt file.

Answer (score 0):

Hari,
JiBX need characters as input. I think you have specified your encoding incorrectly. Try this code instead:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("output.xml");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
groups = (GroupsDTO) uctx.unmarshalDocument(isr);
```

If you must use the code you have written, I would try outputting the text to the console (System.put.println(xxx)) to make sure you are decoding the utf-8 correctly.

Don

Answer (score 0):

Go to to mvn repository path and delete that folder for xml file.

Comment: Since I was seeing this problem with Maven, this solution worked for me. I hesitate to upvote it though, as I don't think the OP was dealing with Maven at all. But for any people who have this problem with Maven in the future, give this one a try.