# How to fix "Path Manipulation Vulnerability" in some Java Code?

Tags: security, fortify, path-manipulation

The below simple java code getting Fortify Path Manipulation error. Please help me to resolve this. I am struggling from long time.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File(args[0]);
    }

}
```

Comment: When are you getting the error? When running it or compiling it? How are you compiling? What are you `import`ing?

Comment: what param value to you pass?

Comment: I am not getting java compilation error, i ran Fortify Sourceanalyzer, then it is showing Path manipulation vulnerability.

Comment: i am not passing anything, i just ran fortify analyzer, then it is showing path manipulatino vulnerability. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you care what Fortify says?  The code self-evidently uses any file it is told to use and has access to.  The risk is only in who gets to tell it what file to open or create.  If you want to open or create **any** file that is specified, then you write code that can -- as in this example.  Without knowing how this program is run, the advice is useless.

Answer (score 22):

Try to normalize the URL before using it

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#normalize()

```
Path path = Paths.get("/foo/../bar/../baz").normalize();
```

or use normalize from *org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils*

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#normalize(java.lang.String)

```
Stirng path = FilenameUtils.normalize("/foo/../bar/../baz");
```

For both the result will be `\baz`

Answer (score 13):

Looking at the OWASP page for [Path Manipulation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Manipulation), it says

> An attacker can specify a path used in an operation on the filesystem

You are opening a file as defined by a user-given input. Your code is almost a perfect example of the vulnerability! Either

1. Don't use the above code (don't let the user specify the input file as an argument)
2. Let the user choose from a list of files that you supply (an array of files with an integer choice)
3. Don't let the user supply the filename at all, remove the configurability
4. Accept the vulnerability but protect against it by checking the filename (although this is the worst thing to do - someone may get round it anyway).

Or re-think your application's design.

Comment: The OWASP recommendation applies to attempts to escape the web root folder in web-based attacks. This doesn't apply to the main() code example in the question because that is user input on the command line. It is not a vulnerability in itself for a user to supply file paths on the command line; they already have access to the command line and all its power. You'd have to be doing something like running software with the setuid bit on for command-line arguments to be a security hole.

Comment: So is fortify unhappy any time I let a user save a file to a location of their choosing? This seems like a very strange vulnerability. What's an example of this actually being an exploit for a non-root user?

Answer (score 7):

Fortify will flag the code even if the path/file doesn't come from user input like a property file. The best way to handle these is to canonicalize the path first, **then** validate it against a white list of allowed paths.

**Bad:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File(args[0]);
    }

}
```

**Good:**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file=new File(args[0]);
        if (!isInSecureDir(file)) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            String canonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();
        if (!canonicalPath.equals("/img/java/file1.txt") &&
            !canonicalPath.equals("/img/java/file2.txt")) {
           // Invalid file; handle error
        }

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    }
```

Source: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/FIO16-J.+Canonicalize+path+names+before+validating+them

Answer (score 3):

Only allow alnum and a period in input. That means you filter out the control chars, "..", "/", "\" which would make your files vulnerable. For example, one should not be able to enter /path/password.txt.

Once done, rescan and then run Fortify AWB.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution to the Fortify Path Manipulation issues.

What it is complaining about is that if you take data from an external source, then an attacker can use that source to manipulate your path. Thus, enabling the attacker do delete files or otherwise compromise your system.

The suggested remedy to this problem is to use a whitelist of trusted directories as valid inputs; and, reject everything else.

This solution is not always viable in a production environment. So, I suggest an alternative solution. Parse the input for a whitelist of acceptable characters. Reject from the input, any character you don't want in the path. It could be either removed or replaced.

Below is an example. This does pass the Fortify review. It is important to remember here to return the literal and not the char being checked. Fortify keeps track of the parts that came from the original input. If you use any of the original input, you may still get the error.

```
public class CleanPath {

    public static String cleanString(String aString) {
        if (aString == null) return null;
        String cleanString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); ++i) {
            cleanString += cleanChar(aString.charAt(i));
        }
        return cleanString;
    }

    private static char cleanChar(char aChar) {

        // 0 - 9
        for (int i = 48; i < 58; ++i) {
            if (aChar == i) return (char) i;
        }

        // 'A' - 'Z'
        for (int i = 65; i < 91; ++i) {
            if (aChar == i) return (char) i;
        }

        // 'a' - 'z'
        for (int i = 97; i < 123; ++i) {
            if (aChar == i) return (char) i;
        }

        // other valid characters
        switch (aChar) {
            case '/':
                return '/';
            case '.':
                return '.';
            case '-':
                return '-';
            case '_':
                return '_';
            case ' ':
                return ' ';
        }
        return '%';
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a solution, but simply obscures the vulnerability and doesn't resolve it. I'd call this a dishonest approach, and recommend that the vulnerability instance be marked as a false positive instead. At least then you have an opportunity to explain why the vulnerability isn't a concern.

Comment: I think this depends on what is meant by "fix" the problem.  Fortify likes to point out things that aren't really issues.  This could be useful information to get around problems with people who misinterpret Fortify results and require unrealistic resolutions.  This fixes the problem if the problem is Fortify and the people looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running Fortify against a web application, during your triage of Fortify vulnerabilities that would likely get marked as "Not an issue". Reasoning being A) obviously this is test code and B) unless you have multiple personality disorder you're not going to be doing a path manipulation exploit against your self when you run that test app.

If very common to see little test utilities committed to a repository which produces this style of false positive.

As for your compilation errors, that generally comes down to classpath issues.

Answer (score 0):

We have code like below which was raising Path Manipulation high category issue in fortify .

```
String.join(delimeter,string1,string2,string2,string4);
```

Our program is to deal with AWS S3 bucket so, we changed as below and it worked .

```
com.amazonaws.util.StringUtils.join(delimeter,string1,string2,string2,string4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Tika library **FilenameUtils.normalize** solves the fortify issue.

```
import org.apache.tika.io.FilenameUtils;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = FilenameUtils.normalize(args[0]); //This line solve issue.
        File file=new File(filePath);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for replacing FileInputStream. You will need to close your project and open again to accurately see whether changes worked.

[File to byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)

Comment: Well I ran into java heap error due to this, so memory needs to be increased.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void extractZipFile(String zipFilePath, String outputFolder) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(zipFilePath);
    
    try (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file)) {
    
    Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zip.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();

            String entryName = entry.getName();

            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                File outputFile = new File(outputFolder, entryName);
                if (!outputFile.toPath().normalize().startsWith(new File(outputFolder).toPath().normalize())) {
                    throw new IOException("Zip entry is outside of the target directory: " + entryName);
                }
                try (InputStream input = zip.getInputStream(entry)) {
                    Files.copy(input, outputFile.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Use `Normalize()` function in C# and it resolved the fortify vulnerability in next scan.

`string s = @:c:\temp\scan.log".Normalize();`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is an answer for C#; the question is for Java.

Answer (score -4):

Use regex to validate the file path and file name

```
fileName = args[0];
final String regularExpression = "([\\w\\:\\\\w ./-]+\\w+(\\.)?\\w+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
boolean isMatched = pattern.matcher(fileName).matches();
```

Comment: What is the regex does here ? What is the regex checks, can you explain ? @user5250723