# Shell script equivalent of Java MessageDigest

Tags: java, shell, cryptography, openssl, sha1

how one can run following Java functionality using shell script only? Shouldn't openssl do the trick? For some reason values are not same.

Shell:

```
$ cat test.txt 
test
$ openssl sha1 test.txt
SHA1(test.txt)= fde773a18bb29f5ed65e6f0a7aa717fd1fa485d4
```

Java code (play framework origin):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public static String hexSHA1() {
    value = "test";
    try {
        MessageDigest md;
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(value.getBytes("utf-8"));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        return byteToHexString(digest);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}


public static String byteToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    // a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
    return String.valueOf(Hex.encodeHex(bytes));
}
```

fde773a18bb29f5ed65e6f0a7aa717fd1fa485d4 != a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3

Comment: Next time, just read the binary data of `test.txt` into Java and see if the digest matches. If it does, check the if the *binary* input of the digest matches the one in the file. To see how to read a binary file, use this Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java (check out the Java 7 way, should be a one liner).

Answer (score 7):

You have a carriage return and line feed at the end of `test.txt`. These are apparently not in your Java string.

```
$ echo -n test > test.txt
$ openssl sha1 test.txt
SHA1(test.txt)= a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3

$ echo -ne 'test\r\n' > test2.txt
$ openssl sha1 test2.txt
SHA1(test2.txt)= fde773a18bb29f5ed65e6f0a7aa717fd1fa485d4
```

Answer (score 0):

Values are not the same as in the first case you're calulating SHA1 for `test.txt` file, in next case you're calculating the same for `test` string.

If you're going to call `openssl` from inside java app use this code snippets:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec('openssl', 'sha1', 'test.txt')