# File to array of byte

Tags: java, arrays

I've used this topic: [File to byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)
Here is my code:

```
try {
  Path path1 = Paths.get(path + fileName);
  byte[] fileAsByte = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
  System.out.println("Byte : " + fileAsByte.toString());
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("File Not Found.");
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
  System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
  e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e3) {
  System.out.println("Out of Memory");
  e3.printStackTrace();
  }
```

This code is not triggering any exception, but the output is still:

```
Byte : [B@60f17a2f
```

Which seems pretty invalid to me. I'm pretty sure I did a dumb error, but it's been three hours that I've been trying to resolve it, and I could use some fresh eyes on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't convert an array directly to `String` and have it readable by the human eye. It is printing out `[` (meaning "array"), then `B` (for `byte`), then `@` and its identity hash code.

To get a list of the bytes in the array, use the static [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(byte[])) method instead:

```
System.out.println("Byte : " + java.util.Arrays.toString(fileAsByte));
```

(If the bytes represent characters for an output string, use [@iTech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1813858/itech)'s solution.)

Answer (score 4):

You should create a `String` instance initialized with your `byte[]`, e.g.

```
System.out.println("Byte : " + new String(fileAsByte));
```

You can also specify the encoding e.g. `new String(fileAsBytes,"UTF-8");`