# is this correct ? how to load bytes from a file?

Tags: java, file, byte, inputstream, bufferedreader

I need to load bytes from a file using Java. is this right ?

```
InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(file); 
InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);                 
String line;
String cle = "" ;
while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
   cle+=line
}
---> cle.getBytes()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java

Answer (score 7):

No, that's definitely *not* the way to do it:

- You're converting the bytes into text as you read them from a file
- You're removing all line-breaks (they're not returned from `readLine`)
- You're converting the text back into bytes

You're very likely to lose data this way.

To load *bytes* you shouldn't be using a `Reader` at all - just use `InputStream`. It's very important to understand that binary data and text data aren't the same. Treating either of them as the other is a really bad idea.

If you just want to read all the data from an file I would personally use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) and its [`Files`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) class:

```
byte[] data = Files.toByteArray(file);
```

Or if you've already got an `InputStream`, use [`ByteStreams`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html):

```
byte[] data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(inputSTream);
```

This also works with [`InputSupplier`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/InputSupplier.html).

Comment: I found this `RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            byte[] cle = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            f.read(cle);` is it okey ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes

```
 byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
```

Comment: I found this `RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r"); byte[] cle = new byte[(int)f.length()]; f.read(cle);` is it okey ?

Comment: Not quite. f.read(cle) returns the actual number of bytes it read. You should keep reading until it return -1.