# Display PDF in a webpage

Tags: spring, pdf, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC, **I want to display PDF file from my local to webpage.** I don't know what should I do to my controller to do this. I see some similar problem with an answer that returning a `ResponseEntity<byte[]>` like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc) but this one is for `ajax` if I'm not mistaken, this is not my requirement.

**Update:**

This is what I tried so far:

```
<a href="#" onClick="test();" >test</a>

function test(){
      $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../admin/module/id.do",
    data: '{ file_id }',
    success: function(response){
           alert(response);
             }
      });
}
```

And the controller:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/module/id", method = RequestMethod.POST )
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF( @PathVariable( "id" )
    int id, Model model )
    {
        System.out.println( "test" );
        Path path = Paths.get( "C:/Users/FORSAK~1/AppData/Local/Temp/spring_tutorial.pdf" );
        byte[] contents = null;
        try
        {
            contents = Files.readAllBytes( path );
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType( MediaType.parseMediaType( "application/pdf" ) );
        String filename = "spring_tutorial.pdf";
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData( filename, filename );
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>( contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK );
        return response;
    }
```

the `alert(response)` doesn't work and also the `System.out.println( "test" );`

The error from the firebug is `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8080/ThesisProject/admin/module/id.do"`

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [id] in @RequestMapping
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter$ServletHandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:857)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolvePathVariable(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:360)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:432)
    ....
```

Comment: The solution you've linked will work for you. It has nothing to do with ajax.

Comment: I don't know how to make it work. Can you give me a working example?

Comment: There's one in the link you posted. Read the pdf you want to send into a `byte[]` and give it to the returned `ResponseEntity`. Don't forget to set the appropriate headers.

Comment: I updated my question can you look at it?

Comment: What's the error server side? Post the stack trace.

Comment: I updated the question with the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, the exception is pretty simple

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find @PathVariable [id] in @RequestMapping
```

And you have

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/admin/module/id", method = RequestMethod.POST )
```

which does not declare a path variable, only a specific path. The `id` is passed as a request parameter

```
data: '{ file_id }',
```

This is wrong by the way, I think it should be

```
data: { id: file_id },
```

Annotate your parameter with `@RequestParam(value = "id")` instead.

Comment: I see but still have an error. Heres the firebug error message `400 Bad Request - http://localhost:8080/ThesisProject/admin/module/id.do"`

Comment: @newbie See my edit. Your javascript is wrong. I think it has to be `id: file_id`. But I don't know jQuery well enough to be sure.

Comment: I see, It's an EL so change it to `{ id: ${file_id} }`, I don't know if it will exactly show the PDF file. How can I display it on my `object` tag to know if it will display a PDF file?

Comment: @newbie Honestly, don't use AJAX to show a PDF. Just go to the page with an `<a>` link.

Comment: I'm going to display multiple PDF files. And the PDF will come from the uploaded PDF's of the user. What implementation should I go with?