# Display PDF in webpage

Tags: java, html, spring, pdf, pdf-conversion

To follow up to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625271/display-pdf-in-a-webpage) I change the code to this:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/{prePath:^tutor$|^admin$}/module/{file_id}" )
public void getModule( @PathVariable( "file_id" )
int fileId, Model model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request )
{
     model.addAttribute( "id", fileId );

     File test = new File( "C:\\resource\\pdf\\test.pdf" );
     response.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/pdf" );
     response.setHeader( "Content-Length", String.valueOf( test.length() ) );
     response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"test.pdf\"" );

     System.out.println( test.toPath() );
     try
     {
         Files.copy( test.toPath(), response.getOutputStream() );
     }
     catch( IOException e )
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

And finally able to display PDF in the webpage. The URL is accessed by:

```
<a href="../admin/module/${ file_id }.do?test" >Spring Tutorial</a>
```

But the PDF file is displaying on the whole page. My PDF is from my local  I want to display it with just a portion of webpage. Maybe a `<div>` or anything that suit the approach best. Any thoughts of how can I do this?

Comment: There is many possibilities, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Comment: @LaurentG `pdf.js` is a bit complicated to me. I don't know where to start. Can you give a sample code of how can I display PDF from a local path.

Answer (score 0):

Just iframe it if the user has adobe pdf then they will be able.to see in in there browser

Comment: The file is from my local resource. I tried `<iframe src="C:/resource/pdf/test.pdf"></iframe>` but it doesn't display anything

Comment: Have you got a server or trying to share the file?

Comment: Because if is local , 1 Noone else can see it , 2 the server wont be able to iframe it and 3 you will need adobe pdf reader

Comment: Also javascript had No I/O Access you need Node.js or PHP, ASP

Comment: The flow is like this. When the user uploaded a file then the web will create a folder where will the PDF store. That path is `C:/resource/pdf/` then from there I want to display the PDF files on a specific portion page.

Comment: Have you got PHP isntalled

Comment: If you have got php check out the answer velow

Comment: Oh yeah sorry ive been learning ASP MVC similar syntax use jsp to printfilecontents

Comment: Actually I'm only new to web programming so I also looking of how can I do this.

Comment: I'm halfway with my project I can't just switch other language to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = "file.pdf";
$read = file_get_contents($file);
echo $read;
?>
```