# Return generated pdf using spring MVC With angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to do the same as in [Return generated pdf using spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc)

But i'm using wkhtmltopdf So i modified the answer of the above question a bit until i get something like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createhtml2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getPDF() throws IOException {


    try {

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", " cd C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin && wkhtmltopdf.exe "
                + "http://google.com C:\\test\\Google.pdf");

        pb.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    Path pdfPath = Paths.get("C:\\test\\Google.pdf");
    byte[] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(pdfPath);


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    String filename = "output.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(pdf, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

I do not know if the above request mapping is right. But at the moment the front end and the back end does not throw any error's.
But how can i now let the user download this pdf file ?

This is the controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('DemoCtrl', DemoCtrl);

    DemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$localStorage' ];
    function DemoCtrl($scope, $http,$localStorage) {


        var vm = this;

        vm.add = add;

        function add() {

            $http.post('/api/createhtml2');

            console.log("Create html page")

        }

    }

})();
```

The html page

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">

    <form ng-submit="vm.add()">

        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" >Create Html Page</button>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: 1) *"I do not know if the above request mapping is right."* use a REST Console/Postman/etc. to validate the server-side code, there's no much point proceeding until you *do* know that 2) you can't download a file via Ajax, search for "angularjs file download" on SO for alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf;charset=utf-8"));
```