# Spring MVC. How do I process JSP to string with model as an argument

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, freemarker

Whats JSPs equivalent of `FreeMarker` class `FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString`  which accepts two arguments (Template template, Object model).

Using FreeMarker, the code looks like:

```
public String getReport(ModelMap model) throws Exception {
    model.addAttribute("name",  "tim");
    String template = "testing.ftl";
    String htmlStr = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(
            freemarkerConfig.getConfiguration().getTemplate(template),
            model);
    // ...
}
```

How can I achieve above using JSP?

Answer (score 0):

Using JSPs you have two options:

1) Fill the model and return the logical name of the view

2) Create and return a `ModelAndView` object

**Controller - Option 1**

```
public String getReport(Model model) throws Exception {

    model.addAttribute("name",  "tim");

    //you should have testing.jsp
    return "testing";
}
```

**Controller - Option 2**

```
public ModelAndView getReport(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("testing");
    modelAndView.addObject("name", "tim");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

In both ways, the view (JSP page) can access the model data as shown bellow.

**testing.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<body>
    <p>${name}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Main reason for string conversion is to generate a pdf document from it and not displaying the page it self.

Comment: Now I understood your requirement. I think that is impossible to do with JSP templates.

Comment: try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc.