# Download a file using POST request with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

for downloading a file using Spring, I'm using GET method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exportar/{tipo}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void exportar(HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable TipoEnum tipo) throws IOException{

File file = service.exportar(tipo);

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", file.getName() + ".xls"));
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"); 
        InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

How can I achieve this using POST? Is this possible?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exportar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: And it doesnt work when you change it to POST? All what you need is set response header to file. You can found inspiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc

Comment: `POST` is a method for POSTing data not for receiving them, so I do not think that using `POST` is a good idea to downloading files.

Comment: agree with you @noname

Answer (score 0):

I just reproduced this error in from within the Insomnia REST client.
Once I added the header:

```
'Content-type': 'application/json'
```

The problem seemed to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my sample working code, I am using ResponseEntity, it can be done without that also.

```
@PostMapping("/document/{documentId}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDocumentById(@Valid @PathVariable Long documentId, ) throws MalformedURLException {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + caseId.toString().concat("_Document.pdf")).body(superBillGenerator.generateSuperBill(caseId, type));
}
```

It was earlier a GET call, but also works fine with POST.