# jpa query to retrieve blob and then send as pdf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pdf, spring-data-jpa

**Repository**

```
// 'doc' is a blob type in oracle table
@Query(value =  "select doc from watever where ROWNUM = 1",  nativeQuery = true)
public byte[] findWatever();
```

**Controller**

```
byte[] reponse = dossierHypothecaireRepository.findWatever();               
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentLength(reponse.length);           
headers.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "out.pdf");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
return new ResponseEntity<>(reponse, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

**Problem**

When I call this controller from a browser and want to display the pdf I get "pdf wont display" or "corrupt file"

I tried with many differents pdfs, browsers and pdfreaders: same error.

=> the problem comes from my code I think.

Edit additional information: 
The file I put in base for my test is  : 430 ko
The downloaded file from the browser is : 420 ko

Comment: true, but actually it's Boba Fett from star wars ;) -
 https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boba_Fett

Comment: along with data you have to pass the format, file Name, file size. here is the simple example https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-write-data-into-PDF-using-servlet

Comment: I tried with this solution for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc  => still the same error.

Comment: @Tyvain have you tried downloading complete file before opening it?

Comment: @Saravana yes, I just tried (see edited code). Can't open the downloaded pdf.. :(

Comment: So how does the original pdf and the downloaded differ? How do they compare to what is stored in the DB?