# Cannot download file: cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist with Spring

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-boot, angular6

I want to implement file download using this Angular 6 code:

Rest API:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadsController.class);

private static final String EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = "/Users/test/Documents/blacklist_api.pdf";

@GetMapping("export")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> export() throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
}
```

Service:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DownloadService} from "../service/download.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {flatMap} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs/index";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  templateUrl: './download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download.component.scss']
})
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
  }

  export() {               
    this.downloadService.downloadPDF().subscribe(res => {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    });         
  } 
}
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DownloadService} from "../service/download.service";
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from "@angular/router";
import {flatMap} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
import {of} from "rxjs/index";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-download',
  templateUrl: './download.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./download.component.scss']
})
export class DownloadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private downloadService: DownloadService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
  }

  export() {               
    this.downloadService.downloadPDF().subscribe(res => {
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank');
    });         
  } 
}
```

When I click download button I get this Spring error:

```
15:28:02,819 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter] (default task-1) Forwarding to error page from request [/downloads/export] due to exception [class path resource [Users/test/Documents/blacklist_api.pdf] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Users/test/Documents/blacklist_api.pdf] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at deployment.test_admin.war//org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:195)
```

The file is present in the directory but looks like it's located outside of the war package and Wildly I can't access it. Is there any way to configure Java to access it and download it?

Comment: Note from the documentation for [`ClassPathResource(path)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#ClassPathResource-java.lang.String-): *A leading slash will be removed, as the ClassLoader resource access methods will not accept it.*

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: I think the larger problem here is that `ClassPathResource` is cannot reference arbitrary parts of the filesystem - it can only find resources from within your current classpath. In this instance, it's also unnecessary - why not just use [`FileInputStream(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream-java.lang.String-)?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using ClasspathResource, you can only get files "*within*" the classpath.

If your file is outside of the classpath you can't get it in that way.

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DownloadsController.class);

private static final String EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH = "/Users/test/Documents/blacklist_api.pdf";

@GetMapping("export")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> export() throws IOException {
    File pdfFile = Paths.get(EXTERNAL_FILE_PATH).toFile();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
    headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    headers.add("Expires", "0");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).contentLength(pdfFile.length())
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(new FileInputStream(pdfFile));
}
```

I changed the way you take the file, for a File and not a ClassPathResource.

I modified that piece of code on the fly, sorry if there's any mistake. I hope it can help

Comment: I get The method contentLength() is undefined for the type File

Comment: Change it for the method length()

Comment: I get error `Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]`

Comment: You might have to set in your getMapping your produceType with something like @GetMapping(path="export", produces="application/pdf")

Comment: Anyway you have an example how to download a pdf file from a REST in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652760/return-generated-pdf-using-spring-mvc/16656382#16656382)

Comment: Unfortunately I get again Could not find acceptable representation. Any idea where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String TEMPLATE_NAME = "filename.csv";

@Value("templates/" + TEMPLATE_NAME)
private ClassPathResource TEMPLATE;

@GetMapping(value = "/download/template", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void getTemplate(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + TEMPLATE_NAME);
    IOUtils.copy(TEMPLATE.getInputStream(), response.getOutputStream());
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```