# Saving file to database in vaadin

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, upload, vaadin

Hello I am trying to save a file into my database using vaadin.  I have a web application which allows the user to upload a file, so far the file uploads to my filesystem.  Here is my code for the upload:

```
public class FileUploader implements Receiver, SucceededListener {
        File file;

        public OutputStream receiveUpload(String fileName, String mimeType) {
            FileOutputStream fos = null;

            try {
                file = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\ABDEN00U\\Desktop\\tmp\\" + fileName);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);   
            } catch (final java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
                new Notification("Could not open file", e.getMessage(), Notification.TYPE_ERROR_MESSAGE.ERROR_MESSAGE).show(Page.getCurrent());
                return null;
            }

            return fos; 
        }

        @Override
        public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            file_upload.setVisible(true);
            file_upload.setSource(new FileResource(file));
        }
```

What I am trying to do is grab the file and convert it to a bytearray and upload it to my postgres database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `uploadSucceeded` method you can convert your `file` into a `byte[]`.

How? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java/5083666#5083666)'s a possible solution.

Then store your `byte[]` into a blob field in your database.