# Struts2 fileInputStream / read file and put it into memory

Tags: java, struts2

I am using struts2 framework for development. The users can download the image from our web page. The following code is worked but i have some question on the following code.

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
<param name="contentType">image/tiff</param>
<param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
<param name="contentDisposition">filename="test.tif"</param>
<param name="bufferSize">20480</param>
</result>
```

When user request the image, the system read the physical file and pass it into fileinputstream.

```
File f = new File("C:/test.tif");
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
```

however, if one or more users request the same images at the same times, is that any problems occur for the above code? If yes, how can i edit the code to avoid the concurrent problems?

1. How can i read the physical file and then put it into memory file then pass the memory file to the client site?

Thanks

Comment: Since you're creating a new FileInputStream, it should be safe. Just make sure you're not modifying it the on the fly. If you don't want to read the file for each request, I would have the file in a Singleton class. Or you can put in a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Struts2 Actions are ThreadSafe**.

They are `ThreadLocal`, every Action has its own instances of the variables.

If three users call that code, three FileInputStreams will be created.

For loading the file into memory, you could read from `fileInputStream` and write to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` ([read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)), but **why** do you want to read all the file in memory and then pass it to the client ? It is useless and expensive, just ***stream*** it to the client with your inputStream. If you set content-length, the browser will draw the progress bar too :|

Assuming you have `private InputStream fileInputStream;` and the related `Getter`, your code is only missing the return value:

```
File f = new File("C:/test.tif");
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
return SUCCESS;
```

Since `java.io.File` represents a file in the File System and NOT an open file, you are safe (the input stream will be closed automatically once the download is finished)