# how to store byte in an array and get back the string

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have to work with byte array and string in java . I read a file using java and and get the byte code from getBytes() method which is [B@1d1cdf7]

Is this possible to work again with this code . In my program to decode back to 
     java   string.
I need byte array so how can i store this value in byte array. I want something 
like in another program i dont have the original text and i have only the byte 
array then how can i get back the string result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while(/* condition */ ) { // Get bytes from the file
        // Append bytes to the byteArray
        stream.write(bytes); 
    }

    String str = new String(stream.toByteArray()); // Get the string representation
```

Comment: ankur in my text file  file i have written the bytes as [B@1d1cdf7] . my query is how can i read this value as byte array

Comment: Use InputStream classes such as FileInputStream to read it as bytes.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Please refer this post on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert getBytes() to String.

```
public String toString(){
   return new String(getBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert string to byte array try this

```
String test = "This is a test";

byte[] bytes = test.getBytes();
System.out.println("Byte : " + bytes);
```

now to convert byte array to string try this

```
String s = new String(bytes);
System.out.println("Text : " + s);
```

**output**

```
Byte : [B@25154f

Text : This is a test
```

Comment: downvoters please tell what is wrong in this code,so that i can rectify it

Answer (score -1):

You can use Base64 encoding. This encoding is more suitable and portable for save binary data into string.

Base64 api in java :

```
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
```