# Struts2 : How to upload file using intercepter?

Tags: jsp, twitter-bootstrap, struts2, upload, interceptor

I try to upload a file (image) using Struts2. But, my file,file content and filename type have a null value !
I tried searching for this problem but without any result.

that is what I'm trying to do :

**jsp :**

```
 <s:form id="registerSubmit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="bootstrap">

<s:textfield name="tel" cssClass="form-control" label="tel :"></s:textfield>

<label for="myFile">Upload your file</label>
<input type="file" name="file" />

<button type="submit" id="submit" > Enregistrer</button>
</s:form>
```

**action :**

```
 public class Gestion extends ActionSupport implements  SessionAware, ModelDriven{

        private Visit c;
        private Service Service;
        private Long tel;
        private File file;
        private String fileContentType;
        private String fileFileName;

            public String addvisit(){

                c = new visit();
                Service = new ServiceImpl();            
                c.setTel(tel);
                System.out.println(fileContentType); //null
                System.out.println(fileFileName); //null
                byte[] bFile = null;
                if(file != null)
                    bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()]; 
                c.setPhoto(bFile); // null

                Service.add(c);



        return "success";

            }
     //setters and getters

    }
```

**struts.xml**

```
<struts>
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="10000000" /> 

    <package name="login" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

    <action name="addvisit" class="action.Gestion"
            method="addvisit">
               <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                    image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success" type="json" >
                    <param name="root">map</param>
            </result>
        </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15256884/573032

Comment: Thanks Roman,I added the jars (commons fileupload and commons io) not "Deployment Assembly" but i still have a null values !

Comment: You have probably read not the best answer.

Comment: what is the best answer ?

Comment: i remove  <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
 and i add <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />, but without any result, any help please Mr Roman !

Comment: What errors are printed to the console?

Comment: when i use this form,I don't have any error because i make a test :  if(file != null) bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()]; bFile have always a null value and i set a null value : c.setPhoto(bFile);

Comment: If you don't have errors then it's probably doing fine. You should provide setter for file if you want the file != null.

Comment: no it's not doing fine because when i try to write fileContentType
and fileFileName, i had the null values !

Comment: Did you try without parameters to interceptor?

Comment: yes, without any result

Comment: Then you need to mess the order of the interceptors if you still doing model driven.

Comment: no, i don't use it with this action !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not pointing to your Action anywhere in your form.

I also suggest you to use (self closed) Struts Tags when possible:

```xml
<s:form action="addvisit" id="registerSubmit" method="post" 
        enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="bootstrap">
    <s:textfield name="tel" cssClass="form-control" label="tel :" />
    <s:file name="file" label="Upload your file" />
    <s:submit id="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
</s:form>
```

That said, your error is 99% related to ModelDriven. Either remove the ModelDriven interface implementation, or configure the stack to have the FileUpload Interceptor *after* the ModelDriven one, like in the default stack (you are actually using two times the FileUpload interceptor):

```
<action name="addvisit" class="action.Gestion" method="addvisit">

    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
        <param name="fileUpload.maximumSize">2097152</param>
        <param name="fileUpload.allowedTypes">
            image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
        </param>            
    </interceptor-ref>

    <result name="success" type="json" >
            <param name="root">map</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Comment: that is not what you showed us... and it won't work. Please add the missing ajax call to get a better help, and consider jQuery or similar solutions for the AJAX upload, or using a standard submit.

Comment: even if i call action from submit button, i still had a null value

Comment: i think the mistake was in interceptor call, because when i used a simple form without model driven and ajax cal, i still have the same problem !

Comment: Now, i get the values of fileContentType and fileFileName, but when i try to convert file to byte[] like this : byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) getFile().length()]; and then i set it : c.setPhoto(bFile), it put null value into database ! any suggestion plase !

Comment: Now ? Which was the problem ? You should accept / upvote the anwser if it helped (file and attributes are not null anymore), and open a new question if you have a new question. Btw [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/859076/1654265) for converting a file to a byte array...

Comment: Thank you... but I'm still curious about what the problem was :) A typo ?

Comment: it was about ajax call !!

Comment: Ohh... I read your `without model driven and ajax cal` like without both, while you was meaning `without model driven and WITH ajax call`... then everything is clear. You can take a look here btw: https://code.google.com/p/ajax-file-upload-struts2/ I've not tried but it seems to suit your needs