# Read bytes from file Java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to parse my file which keeps all data in binary form. How to read N bytes from file with offset M? And then I need to convert it to String using `new String(myByteArray, "UTF-8");`. Thanks!

Here's some code:

```
File file = new File("my_file.txt");
byte [] myByteArray = new byte [file.lenght];
```

UPD 1: The answers I see are not appropriative. My file keeps strings in byte form, for example: when I put string "str" in my file it actually prints smth like [B@6e0b... in my file. Thus I need to get from this byte-code my string "str" again.

UPD 2: As it's found out the problem appears when I use toString():

```
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("db.file")), true), "UTF-8")));
    Iterator it = storage.entrySet().iterator();//storage is a map<String, String>
    while (it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String K = new String(pairs.getKey().toString());
        String V = new String(pairs.getValue().toString);
        writer.println(K.length() + " " + K.getBytes() + " " + V.length() + " " + V.getBytes());//this is just the format I need to have in file
        it.remove();
    }
```

May be there're some different ways to perform that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File to byte\[\] in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)

Comment: Search "Java read binary file" and you should see plenty of examples.  Also look into "Java file seek".

Comment: `[B@6e0b...` is not String written as bytes, it is result of `toString` from byte array, which includes `[B` - byte array; `@` separator; `6e0b...` hexadecimal representation of hashcode of array. Can we see code you used to write string to file?

Comment: @Pshemo But how to get it as real bytes to solve my problem?

Comment: You need to correctly write your sting to file first to be able to read it. Consider using something like `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt"); out.println(yourString);` You will also need to `out.close()` this writer.

Comment: I edited some of your previous question to remove Java from title because it is not needed there. On Stack Overflow there tag system, marking your question with [java] tag is enough to tell us which language you are interested in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of Java 7, reading the whole of a file really easy - just use [`Files.readAllBytes(path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-). For example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("my_file.txt");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

If you need to do this more manually, you should use a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) - your code so far allocates an array, but doesn't read anything from the file.

To read just a *portion* of a file, you should look at using [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), which allows you to seek to wherever you want. Be aware that the `read(byte[])` method does *not* guarantee to read all the requested data in one go, however. You should loop until either you've read everything you need, or use `readFully` instead. For example:

```
public static byte[] readPortion(File file, int offset, int length)
    throws IOException {
  byte[] data = new byte[length];
  try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file)) {
    raf.seek(offset);
    raf.readFully(data);
  }
  return data;
}
```

EDIT: Your update talks about seeing text such as `[B@6e0b..`. That suggests you're calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` at some point. Don't do that. Instead, you should use `new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or something similar - picking the appropriate encoding, of course.

Comment: That doesn't cover the "N bytes at offset M" part.

Comment: @FlorianF: Gah, so it doesn't - I missed that.

Comment: @MaximGotovchits: Your update doesn't show what it thinks it does - all it shows is that calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` doesn't do what you want it to. You've already *got* the code to convert a `byte[]` into a `String` using an appropriate encoding...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I call toString() when I use `new String(pairs.getKey().toString());` 
But `pairs.getKey()` doesn't work without toString =(

Comment: @MaximGotovchits: "doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what's wrong, but I've explained in my answer how to convert a byte array into a string using a particular encoding. If you want anything else, I suggest you ask a separate question after researching others. (It really is a different question from "how do I read a portion of a file into a `byte[]`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I'm sorry for that. Looks like that the main problem was hidden a little bit. So I've updated the question.

Comment: @MaximGotovchits: No, *don't* keep updating the question to drag it further and further away from the original question... especially when I've already provided you with the solution to the new problem anyway. (Don't call `toString()`, call `new String(bytes, charset)`.) If you *must* ask for more information, do so in a new question.