# Reading a file into a byte-array with padding for 8-byte alignment - Java

Tags: java, arrays, io

I need to read a file into a byte array in Java.  Fortunately, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java) has been answered very well, and I am able to use the nio libraries from Java 7.

Here's the twist though: The resulting byte array needs to have a size which is a multiple of 8.  The extra bytes should be null, i.e. \0.

Is there a quick and readable way to pad the byte array with zeros so that its size is a multiple of 8?  Note that readability and speed of development is key here - if the best solution adds more than a few lines in addition simply reading the file into a byte array, I'd rather simply copy the entire buffer into a new array.

Edit:

A bit more reading suggests that I can modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432074/2362578) and simply round the size of the buffer to the next 8.  Any thoughts on the safety and/or effectiveness of this strategy?  I believe the bytes in the buffer beyond the end of the file will be initialized to zero and unaffected by the read - is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 8 is a power of 2, you have a quick way to obtain the next number:

```
int theSize = (orig + 7) & ~7;
```

As to reading into a byte array directly, you say you use nio; therefore allocate a `ByteBuffer` of the requested size and [`.read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read-java.nio.ByteBuffer-) into it from the channel associated with the file (use `FileChannel.open()`). Then get the underlying array using the `.array()` method of `ByteBuffer`. (note: DO NOT `.allocateDirect()`! Otherwise `.array()` won't work)

It would have been ideal if you could `FileChannel.map()` to the wanted size, unfortunately mapping to a greater size modifies the underlying file, so no dice here...

---

Sample code:

```
final Path path = Paths.get("path/to/wanted/file");

try (
    final FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
) {
    final int bufsize = ((int) channel.size() + 7) & ~7;
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufsize);
    channel.read(buf);
    return buf.array();
}
```

Comment: Nifty way of rounding to the nearest 8.  I will probably use the method in the second answer I linked to, and use your formula for computing the next index.

Comment: Based on the `ReadableByteChannel` interface, I don't think this is guaranteed to read the whole file in one go.  Of course, the answer I linked to also has this problem, but at least the `RandomAccessFile` has a `readFully` method I can use instead.  How would you address this issue when using `FileChannel`?

Comment: Hmm, using this method it never failed to read the whole file for me... The doc is kind of unclear indeed, but then a simple loop will fix that: `do { channel.read(buf); } while (buf.position() < channel.size());`