# Reading bytes from a file

Tags: java, fileinputstream, inputstreamreader

I am reading from a ".264" file using code below.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{

    BufferedReader br = null;try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.264"),"ISO-8859-1"));
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(sCurrentLine);      
        }
        String tempdec = new String(asciiToHex(stringBuffer.toString()));
        System.out.println(tempdec);
        String asciiEquivalent = hexToASCII(tempdec);
        BufferedWriter xx = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/yuvplayer-2.3/video dinalized/testret.264"),"ISO-8859-1"));
        xx.write(asciiEquivalent);
        xx.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Opening input and output file in HEX Editor show me some missing values, e.g. `0d` (see pictures attached).

Any solution to fix this?

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: You are reading a binary file in a text mode. In the latter, lines are separate by `0d` characters (CR).

Comment: How to read it properly then?

Comment: The short answer is *you open it as a byte stream* and there is an example here (it stores the bytes in memory, you need to write them in a file): [File to byte\[\] in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java). But beyond that you should clarify your need, other solutions may be better optimized.

Comment: Don't post picture of text. Post the text. Waste of your time and our bandwidth.

Comment: The easiest way to read all the bytes from a file is with `java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes`. Also here is an advice for posting screenshots (if you really have to) - Select a window and press alt-print to capture a screenshot of only that window. Then paste that into paint and save it as png (not jpg) and afterwards send it through tinypng.com. That way your images will be very small. The screenshots you posted would probably be around 40 kb in size plus have better quality than your jpgs. But don't try to convert a jpg to png. That would result in a huge image instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lose `InputStreamReader` and `BufferedReader`, just use `FileInputStream` on its own.
No character encoding, no line endings, just bytes.
Its Javadoc page is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), that should be all you need.

Tip if you want to read the entire file at once: `File.length()`, as in

```
File file = new File("test.264");
byte[] buf = new byte[(int)file.length()];
// Use buf in InputStream.read()
```