# Reading and writing bytes from/to a file

Tags: java, arrays, file, byte

I'm trying to write an array of bytes to a file and read them afterwards. It's important that the the array of bytes that I write is the same as the one that I read. I tried some methods that were suggested here ([File to byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)). However when I apply them I end up reading a different array that I initially wrote.

Here's what i tried:

```
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

//import java.nio.file.Files;
//import java.nio.file.Path;
//import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;

public class FileConverter {

    public static void ToFile(byte[] bytes, String pathName) throws IOException{
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(pathName);
        f.write(bytes);
        f.close();
    }

    public static byte[] ToBytes(String pathName) throws IOException{
        //Path path = Paths.get(pathName);
        //byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        //FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(pathName);
        //byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(f);

        File file = new File(pathName);
        byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
        return bytes;
    }

}
```

my test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FileConverterTest {

    @Test
    public void leesSchrijf() throws IOException{
        String test = "test";
        String pathName = "C://temp//testFile";
        byte[] bytes = test.getBytes();
        FileConverter.ToFile(bytes, pathName);
        Assert.assertEquals(bytes, FileConverter.ToBytes(pathName));
   } 
}
```

Whenever I execute the test class my results vary and the arrays never match.
e.g. java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[B@a3a7a74> but was:<[B@53d5aeb> (first execution)

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[B@29643eec> but was:<[B@745f0d2e> (next execution)

I'm fairly new to test classes and I'm no java genius. So I wondered whether I was doing something incorrectly. If not, is there a way to preserve the byte array while writing it to a file?

Comment: looking at your error message, i am starting to wonder if there is a problem with the conversion. In fact bytes.length=test.length(). Try this.A byte is a Character.

Comment: You're not comparing the contents of the byte arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Junit test you are comparing object references instead of object content. What perhaps you wanted to achieve is to compare the content of byte arrays. You can use `Assert.assertArrayEquals` by importing `import org.junit.Assert;` E.g.

`Assert.assertArrayEquals(bytes, FileConverter.ToBytes(pathName));`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `Assert.assertEquals` is using `euqlas` method to compare objects, but arrays don't override its `equals` method, they inherit it from `Object` class and it is using `==` operator which compares references, not state of object.

To compare content of arrays you need to iterate over them and compare their elements.

You can also use `Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2)` helper method which will do it for you. There is also `Arrays.deepEquals` if you would want to compare multidimensional arrays.

You can use it like

```
Assert.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(arr1, arr2));
```

or in much cleaner way

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

also implements Serializable interface and generate a private static final long serialVersionUID in your FileUtils class.