# Why the result is different for twice common-codec md5

Tags: java, inputstream, md5

when I use apache common-codec `md5Hex` to get the inputstream's md5 result,but get the different result for twice. the example code is below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "D:\\test.jpg";
    File file = new File(data);
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String digest = null, digest2 = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(is.hashCode());
        digest = DigestUtils.md5Hex(is);
        System.out.println(is.hashCode());

        digest2 = DigestUtils.md5Hex(is);
        System.out.println(is.hashCode());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Digest = " + digest);
    System.out.println("Digest2 = " + digest2);
}
```

and the result is:

```
1888654590
1888654590
1888654590
Digest = 5cc6c20f0b3aa9b44fe952da20cc928e
Digest2 = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Thank you for answer!

Comment: I think (but I may be very wrong, hence this is a comment and not an answer) that you shouldn't try hashing a `Stream`. A stream is a data source, and you usually try to hash the data itself, not where it's coming from. So, I think you should either stream out all the data from the file and hash the result (a byte[] probably), of hash the `File` directly. As to why the hash is different, I can guess that it is because the stream changes its state while your read it, so the hash changes too.

Comment: @francesco yes ! use the byte[] is better way,Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` is the md5 hash of the empty string (`""`).

That is because `is` is a stream, meaning that once you've read it (in `DigestUtils.md5Hex(is)`), the "cursor" is at the end of the stream, where there is no more data to read, so attempting to read anything will return 0 bytes.

I suggest reading the contents of the stream to a `byte[]` instead, and hashing that.
For how to get a `byte[]` from an `InputStream`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/858980/2302862).

Comment: Thank you , too silly to not find out that the `""`‘s md5 value:(,now, I now the reason why this problem take

Answer (score 3):

The `InputStream` can be traversed only once. The first call traverses it and returns the MD5 for your input file. When you call `md5hex` the second time, the `InputStream` points to the end-of-file, thus the `digest2` is the MD5 for [empty input](https://www.google.com/search?q=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move back within InputStream. So invoking twice:

```
DigestUtils.md5Hex(is);
```

is not the same. Better read into byte array and use:

```
public static String md5Hex(byte[] data)
```