# Nullpointer exception while creating bitmap from text in android

Tags: java, android, string, text, bitmap

I have text file that has got datas in "%02x " format. For example my text's content like "AA 00 11 CC...". I want to have bitmap from this text file.

I have tried many solutions about this. Firstly I have converted this datas to byte array like that;

```
    Inputstream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ep2data);
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

    String line;
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String s = text.toString();

    //convert string to byte array
    String[] tokens = s.split(" ");
    Log.d("string array length", "" +tokens.length);
    byte[] data = new byte[tokens.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i++) {

        data[i] = (byte) ((Character.digit(tokens[i].charAt(0), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(tokens[i].charAt(1), 16));

    }

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
```

As a result, I'm getting bitmap as null. So I can not create bitmap from this text. How can I create bitmap from text string. I have tried many solution but I couldn't get solution about this subject.

Comment: have you tried the solutions in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java

Comment: `... in "%02x " format` It's a **binary** file. You opened it into a text editor which can handle binary and shows it to you as hex bytes.