# Reading binary from any type of file

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way that I can read the binary data of a file into a string.
I've found one that reads the bytes directly and converts the bytes to binary, the only problem is that it takes up a significant amount of RAM.

Here's the code I'm currently using

```
try {
    byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) sellect.length()];
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sellect);
    in.read(fileData);
    in.close();
    getBinary(fileData[0]);
    getBinary(fileData[1]);
    getBinary(fileData[2]);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the `getBinary()` method

```
public String getBinary(byte bite) {
    String output = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(bite & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
    System.out.println(output); // 10000001
    return output;
}
```

Comment: If the whole "binified" file won't fit in memory, then perhaps the solution is only to work on a portion of the file at a time?

Comment: So are you just converting the 1st 3 bytes of the file? Or is the above just an example? How big do you expect the files to be? As John pointed out, you can read the file in chunks, and increment through a large file that way.

Comment: @John Hascall Makes sense, though I have no idea how you could grab out byte by byte through a file, as maybe it would be great to have some sort of "for" loop running taking in maybe 10 bytes at a time, processing it, then outputting it to a safe place, clearing the memory for that, then repeating as many times as it needs.

Comment: @philbrooksjazz Sorry for not being clear, that is merely a test to see if it would work, yes, I am planning on doing it to the entire file.

Comment: @Dankrushen, the `read()` method only reads as many bytes as your byte array is big.  So you could do: `byte[] fileData = new byte[1024];` and each `read()` will just read the next 1024 bytes. (You can use whatever size seems appropriate).

Comment: @JohnHascall Sounds like what I need, although, how would I go about reading again, but at 1024 bytes in, or 2048, e.t.c bytes in?

Comment: You would use a loop like in @Tony Ruth's answer.  Java will keep track of the position in the file for you -- each read will pick up where the last one left off.

Comment: @JohnHascall Alright, I understand it entirely now, the "read" method has three possible arguments: Where to put the data, where to start reading the data, and how many bytes to read. Using method will get the bytes convert them, and add how many lines read to the offset. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do something like this:

```
int buffersize = 1000;
int offset = 0;
byte[] fileData = new byte[buffersize];

int numBytesRead;
String string;
while((numBytesRead = in.read(fileData,offset,buffersize)) != -1)
{
 string = getBinary(fileData);//Adjust this so it can work with a whole array of bytes at once
 out.write(string); 
 offset += numBytesRead;
 }
```

This way, you never store more information in the ram than the byte and string structures. The file is read 1000 bytes at a time, translated to a string 1 byte at a time, and then put into a new file as a string. Using read() returns the value of how many bytes it reads.

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you :

[File to byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)

> public static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream input) throws IOException
>
> Gets the contents of an InputStream as a byte[]. This method buffers
>   the input internally, so there is no need to use a
>   BufferedInputStream.
>
> Parameters: input - the InputStream to read from Returns: the
>   requested byte array Throws: NullPointerException - if the input is
>   null IOException - if an I/O error occurs