# Android | How Read file to byte array?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to sent file from phone to my device (HC-06 on board). But i need to send it part by part. How i can read file to byte array? I have my own transfer protocol..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File to byte\[\] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To read a `File` you would be best served with a `FileInputStream`.

You create a `File` object pointed to your file on the device. You open the `FileInputStream` with the `File` as a parameter.

You create a buffer of `byte[]`. This is where you will read your file in, chunk by chunk.

You read in a chunk at a time with `read(buffer)`. This returns -1 when the end of the file has been reached. Within this loop you must do the work on your buffer. In your case, you will want to send it using your protocol.

Do not try to read the entire file at once otherwise you will likely get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

```
File file = new File("input.bin");
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
    int read = 0;

    while((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        // Do what you want with the buffer of bytes here.
        // Make sure you only work with bytes 0 - read.
        // Sending it with your protocol for example.
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found: " + e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception reading file: " + e.toString());
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer with code example, i ll try it that way!!

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me, in an android project so hopefully, it will work for you.

```
byte[] fileContent = getByte(path); // call the method from there....


     private byte[] getByte(String path) {
        byte[] getBytes = {};
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            getBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
            is.read(getBytes);
            is.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return getBytes;
    }
```