# Read file to byte array using uri

Tags: java, android

I need to use uri to load file. Uri cannot be converted to absolute path (external volume).

I found example:

```
private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    parcelFileDescriptor.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

But I can't understand how to modify it to read in bytes.

Comment: You mean read the file and hook it into a byte array right?

Comment: Simple Google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939527/android-how-read-file-to-byte-array. I'm already using FileInputStream for absolute paths, but now I need to make it working with uri.

Comment: `"to read in bytes"`? what do you mean? you have: `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` so use that `InputStream` for reading

Comment: @pskink, I see... But how exactly I should use it?

Comment: how to use `InputStream`? it has `int read (byte[] b)` method for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pskink said, your main problem is that you are wrapping your InputStream in a Reader. A Reader is meant to decode bytes into characters, which is, by defintion, what you want to avoid. You need to allocate a buffer and use the InputStream's read method to fill it.

Keep in mind that you have to know the amount of incoming bytes or read multiple times while processing the already received data.

Alternatively, you could use the read method to get an int, check whether the stream has ended, then cast that int to a byte and process one by one. But usually, you want to use a buffer, since that's faster.

Comment: Something like this? `InputStream inputstream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
  
   data = new byte[4*1024];
   int bytesRead = inputstream.read(data);
   
   while(bytesRead != -1) {
   bytesRead = inputstream.read(data);
   }
   inputstream.close();`

Comment: It's hard to read in a comment, but it looks like a good start. ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.craftychild.com/image-files/kids-paint-center.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
File file = new File("D:\\picture\demo.jpg");
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg",file);
```

Comment: You can do for the image file

Comment: URL is not uri.

Comment: URIs identify and URLs locate; however, locators are also identifiers, so every URL is also a URI