# Store *.xls *.csv *.xlsx into Microsoft Sql Server

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-poi

I have a java application with `apache-poi 3.5`.

My database is `Microsoft Sql Server`.

In my application i do an upload and i want to know if it's possible to store my file (`*.xls`, `*.csv`, `*.xlsx`) directly in my database ?

Comment: Are you trying to store the file itself (i.e. as a BLOB), or the data in the file (i.e. importing the spreadsheet into a SQL table?). Either way, yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider converting the files to their binary equivalent (a `byte[]`) and using a `VARBINARY(MAX)` field to store the contents as well as the file name so that you could properly reconstruct the file) :

```
// Retrieve the byte[] data for your file
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(new File("/path/to/file").toPath());
// Write this data to a VARBINARY(MAX) field in SQL here
```

There are a variety of approaches to handle this, but this would be the most naive approach.

Comment: ok, so how can i do to convert my file to their binaey .?

Comment: There are quite a few ways to handle this as well. [This related discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/858980/557445) addresses a variety of them, so it's just a matter of preference. Basically, you just want to pass in your file name or an `InputStream` that is pointed to your file and retrieve the corresponding data of the file a `byte[]`, so you can store that in your database.

Comment: i use java 1.5 there is no `Files` method

Comment: Ah. Any of the other solutions [in the thread I mentioned earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/858980/557445) should be sufficient. They generally require some includes (as the `Files` option was introduced in JDK 7 apparently).

Comment: yes all right, so how can do the reverse, get `VARBINARY` and recreate my file ?