# Unexpected error with readFileToByteArray from FileUtils android

Tags: android, fileutils

Some time ago I used this line for getting byteArray:

```
val data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)
```

But right now I see this error:

```
Unresolved reference: readFileToByteArray
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858980/file-to-byte-in-java) question but maybe we have some another comfort solution without adding sctrict conditions?

Comment: Check FileUtils contain readFileToByteArray function over there or not ?

Comment: @Abhishek, no it doesn't contain this function, but I used it before, what happened?

Comment: Did you update anything in gradle or did something relate upgrading ?

Comment: @Abhishek, maybe yes, I saw suggestion about kotlin and at project module I have updated everything

Comment: Try resolving with that approach check which FileUtils imported in your class.

Comment: it is imported,I have just checked

Comment: If you want to to use that particular function then you need to work from root or else I suggest you to use different approach to read file data.

Comment: from which root? device root?

Comment: Root mean you need to check which FIleUtils is imported and why it does not have that function does it update or something.

Comment: where I can check it?