Pack Mp3 into Dat file and play the audio
I have a some Mp3 files (song.mp3) and I want to pack all of them into a single dat file (mp3s.dat) and be able to load and play the audio from the dat file. I know its possible because you can do it with midis but i'm not sure how to do it with either. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!
I tried to pack the Mp3s into the Mp3.dat which I succeeded in sort of anyways here is the code:
public void packAFile() {
            ArrayList<File> filesToPack = new ArrayList<File>();
            int amountToPack = getAmountOfFilesInFolder(signlink.findcachedir()+"/Mp3/");
            File[] file = new File(signlink.findcachedir()+"/Mp3/").listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < amountToPack; i++) {
                filesToPack.add(file[i]);
                try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(signlink.findcachedir()+"/Mp3/MP3.dat"); ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
                    oos.writeObject(filesToPack);
                    oos.close();
                    fos.close();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


And this is the read packed files method:
ArrayList<File> unpackedMp3s = new ArrayList<File>();
        
        public void readMp3Dat() {
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(signlink.findcachedir()+"/Mp3/MP3.dat");
                     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);){
                unpackedMp3s = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
                    ois.close();
                    fis.close();

                    System.out.println("UnpackedMp3s = " + unpackedMp3s);
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

           }

and the method i tried to play the song with:
public void playMp3FromDat(String song) {
            readMp3Dat();
            for(File songToPlay : unpackedMp3s) {
                if(song.equalsIgnoreCase(songToPlay.getName())) {
                    MP3 s = new MP3(song);
                    s.play();
                }
                System.out.println("Songs: "+songToPlay.getName());
            }
            
        }

EDIT:
To make my question very... very clear: I want to pack multiple .Mp3 files into ONE .dat file and then be able to read the .dat file for a specific .Mp3 file and play the .Mp3 file (Example: Pack song1.mp3, song2.mp3, song3.mp3, song4.mp3 into MP3.dat. Then read MP3.dat for song3.mp3 and play song3.mp3)

Looks like you've got everything you need. What's your question?

it doesn't play the audio, I don't think i did it properly...

Hello mharner, welcome, java no have support for mp3, only wav, aiff and aif, you need javafx, or external library.

So my program can play mp3s the problem is they take up too much space so I was hoping to be able to pack them into a .dat and read them from that when I needed them to save some space. right now it uses about 90mb and when its packed into a .dat its only 3.46mb. How can I read the audio files from the .dat and play them?

You have mistaken the File class to be the contents of the files. In the documentation it explains it is: "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.".
What you really want is instead to get the contents of each file. You can read the contents of a file by creating a FileInputStream:
InputStream in=new FileInputStream(file)

Read the contents into a byte array (byte[]) to save them. You may want to create some class to contain the file contents and some metadata like the name. for example if you call it Mp3File then instead of a file array File[] you will have an Mp3File[] array. Adapt the code to the new format and it should work.

Thanks! I will attempt that, im not sure I fully understand what you mean though I'm a visual learner so examples are very helpful. None the less though I will give it my best shot! I'll report what I find

You can use the method Files.readAllBytes() to read the contents of a file. See this answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5083666/721855

Thank you! I forgot to update you on my progress, I've got the music files packed properly now. Now I'm just having a hard time getting them to open... (play the audio)

So the problem from the question is solved?

no, I still don't think I even packed them right, I'm trying to pack multiple mp3s into one .dat and then read the .dat, take one of the mp3 files and play them.
